# Binary tree insert ( only get the last item....)

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to load a file which has couple of infor, and I want to add them into a binary tree. For sure there is no problem with addToTree and printPreOrder functions, but i don't know why I can only print ( or maybe add ) the last item in the file. Whats the problem?

```
newTree = createBinTree(&cmpInt, &destroyNode);
newRes = createRes();
while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(newRes->name,strtok(buffer, ","));
    strcpy(newRes->food,strtok(NULL, ","));
    newRes->star = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
    addToTree(newTree, newRes);
}
printPreOrder(newTree, &printNode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always adding to the same pointer to `newRes`. While reading you overwrite your previous `newRes` entries. You need to call `createRes` for each object you are reading.